# How can I overload the subscript operator in order to be commutative

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In the following declaration:

```
int arr[10];
```

both of these assignments are valid:

```
arr[0] = 0;

1[arr] = 1;
```

How can I implement an `operator[]` function to be commutative?

Suppose we have this class:

```
class Arr
{
private:
    int a, b, c, d;
public:
    int& operator[](...)
  ...
}
```

And we want to acces `Arr obj;` ==> `obj[1]` returns `b` and also `1[obj]` returns `b`

How can I do this?

Comment: do you really want that? or why do you want it? `1[arr]` being valid is a side-effect of what is going on behind the scences rather than something desirable.

Comment: Yes, I would like to learn how is implemented, maybe it would be useful someday

Comment: Arays are not implemented as C++ classes. You can't replicate this behaviour (fortunately).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. `operator[]` needs to be overloaded as a member function of its left-hand operand's type, which is not possible with integer types.

Comment: which is `the body of its left-handed operand's type`?

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu a poorly worded version of "member function"... Edited.